# Upper density versus upper Banach density on $\omega$

Tags: nt.number-theory, measure-theory

For $A\subseteq\omega$ we define the *upper density* by $$d_u(A) = \lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap n|}{n+1}.$$ For $y\in \omega$ we set $A - y:= \{|a\setminus y|:a\in A\}.$ Note that $|a\setminus y|$ equals the difference of $a$ and $y$ if $a\geq y$, and $0$ otherwise. The *upper Banach density* is defined by $$d_{uB}(A) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\big(\sup 
\{\frac{|(A-y)\cap n|}{n+1}: y\in\omega\}\big).$$
It is easy to see that $d_{uB}(A) \geq d_{u}(A)$ for all $A\subseteq \omega$.

**Question.** What is an example of $A\subseteq \omega$ with $d_{uB}(A) > 0$ and $d_u(A) = 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it is fairly straightforward to get such a set. You can simply get the set as a union of intervals:$\newcommand{\intrvl}[2]{\langle{#1},#2)}\newcommand{\intrvr}[2]{({#1},#2\rangle}\newcommand{\limti}[1]{\lim\limits_{{#1}\to\infty}}$
$$A=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\omega} \intrvr{a_n}{b_n}.$$
And you choose the intervals in a suitable way. You want them long enough to get $d_{uB}(A)=1$. And, at the same time, you want start each interval far enough to keep $d_u(A)=0$. So it suffices to choose them in such way that
\begin{align*}
\limti n (b_n-a_n)=\infty\\
\limti n \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n (b_k-a_k)}{b_n}=0
\end{align*}
The first conditions will help you to get upper Banach density (a.k.a. upper uniform density) equal to one. And the second condition will keep the [asymptotic density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) (natural density) zero.

For example, you can take $a_n=2^n$ and $b_n=2^n+n$.

Several posts on this site are a bit related - and the answers include some references which might be useful:

- [On the independence of lower and upper asymptotic and Banach densities](https://mathoverflow.net/q/206801)
- [Prescribed values for the uniform density](https://mathoverflow.net/q/103111)
- [Density of a set of natural numbers whose differences are not bounded.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/66191)
- [References on density of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/126745) (on Mathematics Stack Exchange)